# Guardar informacion en un csv sin que se repitan (php)

Tags: php, csv

Busco una manera de guardar variables en un archivo **csv** les dejo un ejemplo de lo que e logrado:

```
$enlace="http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php";

$Z = md5($enlace);
$A = substr($Z,0,2); //Obtenemos los primeros 2 caracteres del hash
$B = substr($Z,16,2); //Obtenemos 2 caracteres a partir del caracter 16
$C = substr($Z,30,2); //Obtenemos 2 caracteres a partir del caracter 30
$D = substr($Z,23,1); //Obtenemos 1 caractere a partir del caracter 23
$name = $A.$B.$C.$D; //Juntamos todo    

$f = fopen("demosaved.csv", "a");
fputcsv($f, array($name, $enlace));
fclose($f);
```

Explico la variable **$enlace** no es la misma cuando actualizo la pagina pero en ocasiones se repite y se termina por guardar aunque esta repetida .

Lo que busco es alguna manera de comparar el contenido del csv y si se encuentra repetida la variable **$name** y **$enlace** dentro del archivo csv no guarde las columnas  Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me llevo tiempo pero encontré la solución mas simple :

```
$enlace="http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgetcsv.php";

$Z = md5($enlace);
$A = substr($Z,0,2); //Obtenemos los primeros 2 caracteres del hash
$B = substr($Z,16,2); //Obtenemos 2 caracteres a partir del caracter 16
$C = substr($Z,30,2); //Obtenemos 2 caracteres a partir del caracter 30
$D = substr($Z,23,1); //Obtenemos 1 caractere a partir del caracter 23
$name = $A.$B.$C.$D; //Juntamos todo    

$RN = $name.",".$enlace;

$pagina = file_get_contents('demosaved.csv');
$pos = strpos($pagina, $RN);

// Nótese el uso de ===. Puesto que == simple no funcionará como se espera
if ($pos === false) {
    echo "La cadena '$RN' no fue encontrada en la cadena dada <br/>";
$f = fopen("demosaved.csv", "a");
fputcsv($f, array($name, $enlace));
fclose($f);
} else {
    echo "La cadena '$RN' fue encontrada en la cadena dada";
    echo " y existe en la posición $pos";
}
```

Bueno espero le resulte de utilidad a cualquier otro. Saludes